# Extended classes and Doctrine 2.2

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I'm working on a project using the Zend Framework and Doctrine 2.2. The project makes user of multiple user types. Each user type has it's own database model, and so I want to extend a base "User" class to abstract some of the common functions I need to perform across all users.

Let's say I have a

```
Model_Profile
```

model and a

```
Model_Artist
```

model. Both of these are types of user, and so I wish them to both extend

```
Model_User_Abstract
```

All the scripts run fine until I try to run Doctrine's

```
orm:schema-tool:update --force
```

This results in a php error 'Model_User_Abstract' not found. I don't actually want any inheritance within the database as such, I just want to extend a class that will be used solely within my application.

Any ideas on how to make Doctrine allow this?